# TYPO3 9.5.x feuser with uppercase letters

Tags: settings, case-sensitive, typo3-9.x

I want to allow upper case letters for frontendusers in TYPO3 9.5.x.
When a new feuser self-registers via sfregister_form, it works, but when I add a feuser in the backend, the username gets converted to only lowercase letters.
I found solutions here in the forum https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/47903/ how to (propably) change it, but they only work in older versions of TYPO3. Since there has been lot of changes in TYPO3 since the 10 years old post and I found nothing that talks about TYPO3 9.5.x I ask the question here.

Comment: It would be easier if you told us what solution you found.

Comment: @biesior I added one of the solutions that I found, but I guess there has been a lot of changes and there is probably a completely different way to solve it in newer TYPO3 Versions.

Comment: But tell us which one :D so I can check if it's valid or not. In general, you can modify it with `$GLOBALS['TCA']`. It always better to inform in the question what wxactly you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `username` field has set `lower` eval among others, the fast solution is rewriting it, i.e. if you have some own extension you can add this to its `ext_table.php` or `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php`

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['columns']['username']['config']['eval'] = 'nospace,trim,uniqueInPid,required';
```

Note: you can do it within two files, and nowadays the second is more advised

Note 2: Since TYPO3 ver `7.3` typo3conf/extTables.php is deprecated https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.3/Deprecation-65344-ExtTables.html

- `typo3conf/ext/yourext/ext_tables.php`
- `typo3conf/ext/yourext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php`

Works with `9.5.x` as shown on screenshots:

[image: feuser editing]

[image: TCA Configuration preview]

Comment: I understand now, and it works. Thank you for helping me out! I hope it helps someone else, too.